# Could I test by iOS sandbox account when using enterprise program

Tags: in-app-purchase, sandbox, storekit

I can do sandbox testing in standard program, but in enterprise program, I can't test it because it has different bundle identifier. StoreKit responds that could not find product.

How can I test in enterprise program?

- standard program bundle identifier : aaa.bb.ccc
- enterprise program bundle identifier : aaa.bb.ccc.eee